# How to use of term "both"?

Tags: word-order

In which of the sentences would the **"both"** be right, grammatically?

> a) "Such conditions are **both** dominant during the..."
>
> b) "Such conditions are dominant **both** during the..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context.

> a) "Such conditions are **both** dominant during the..."

If there are *exactly two* conditions that are dominant during a specified period.

or

> b) "Such conditions are dominant **both** during the..."

If there are some number of conditions dominant during *exactly two* seperate periods.

So both can be correct, depending on what comes after the "..."

---

For example:

> Red and blue are **both** dominant colours of national flags.

here we see exactly two things (red and blue) that are dominant.

or

> Red and blue are dominant, **both** in national flags, and in political party colours.

here we see red and blue dominant in exactly two things.

[EDIT: as user Ruakh has said the following is not correct, a comma is not necessary.]

One important thing to note is that the second example *"dominant **both**"* should have a comma after *"dominant"*. Since it does not, in the absense of context I would say example (a) is more likely to be correct.

Comment: Version "a" also has another possible reading that you've missed; see Werrf's answer.

Comment: Re: "the second example *'dominant **both**'* should have a comma after *'dominant'*": Absolutely not. Your example should actually be written as "Red and blue are dominant both in national flags and in political party colours."

Answer (score 3):

Well...**both** of them! With slightly different meanings.

The word **both** is used to indicate the beginning of a list of two items; the list is normally going to be separated by *and*.

The first sentence would make sense if the conditions are dominant in one situation, and irrelevant in a second situation.

> Such conditions are **both** dominant during the first phase of the test, *and* sidelined during the third phase.

The second example would make sense if you're going to list two situations where the conditions are dominant.

> Such conditions are dominant **both** during the first phase of the test *and* during the third phase.

**Both** indicates that whatever has come before it is applicable to two items that follow it. So the first example could be written thus:

> *Such conditions are* dominant during the first phase of the test. *Such conditions are* sidelined during the third phase of the test.

The second example could be written as:

> *Such conditions are dominant* during the first phase of the test. *Such conditions are dominant* during the third phase of the test.

Comment: The first sentence has another possible (and IMHO more likely) reading that you've missed; see Fummy's answer.